# UK passport for Canadian

Tags: canada, uk-citizenship

My father was born in the UK in 1944 to a British mother and Canadian father. In 1947 they moved to Canada, where I was born in 1975. Though he is now a Canadian citizen does my father's birth in England qualify me for British citizenship? If so, what is the procedure?

Comment: yes duplicate of linked question in above comment. I have the almost identical situation expect I am born in Australia in 1976 and my father in England in 1947. I hold a UK passport. You will need your father's and mothers' birth certificate as well as your own to complete the application.

Comment: Does my father's birth in the UK quality me for British citizenship as he is now a Canadian?

Comment: You should check this website: https://www.gov.uk/register-british-citizen